# A problem concerning the limit of a univariate function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Assuming a smooth positive function $f(t)$ that is monotonically increasing on the interval $[0,+\infty)$ with an upper bound $A$, where $A$ is a certain positive constant.

Its derivative $f'(t)$ (a non-negative function) is equal to $0$ at a point $t_0$ if and only if the value of $f$ at that point is A, i.e., $f'(t_0)=0$ iff $f(t_0)=A$.

Furthermore, we have $f'(t)$ converges to $0$ as $t$ tends to $+\infty$.

Can these conditions guarantee that the limit of $f(t)$ is exactly the constant $A$?

I attempted a rigorous proof, but I failed. Perhaps these conditions are still insufficient?

Please help me, I'm very grateful.

Comment: @DumperDGarb I'm sorry. The sentence has been completed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's very much possible that $f'$ has no zeros, $A>\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\notin\operatorname{im}f$. Namely take $A=5$ and $f(x)=\frac\pi2+\arctan x$. However, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\in\operatorname{im}f$, then indeed $f$ is eventually constant equal to $A$. But that is the case as soon ad $f$ is weakly increasing and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\in\operatorname{im}f$ without all those other hypothesis.